# COnverting web app to ipad app(device detection/event handling)

Tags: ipad, html, device-orientation, device-detection

I need to convert a web app into ipad app. Stressing on style and events.

1. How to detect device?
2. How to identify touchevnts?
3. How to map click to touch,doubleclick to doubletap
4. How to capture orientation change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the framework and techniques you used for the original web-app. There are plenty of frameworks out there to build an iOS-web-app. For example [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), you also might want to have a look into [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/).

For the first few steps I can really recommendend reading this [free aviable book from o'reilly](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/index.html) about creating iPhone-Apps with HTML, CSS and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a broad question. But here are answers to some of your questions to quick start.

How to detect device?

use UIDevice to detect iPhone (UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)

How to capture orientation change?

UIInterfaceOrientation

You have to see,for rest of ur questions, InterfaceBuilder Outlets & Action and delegate & datasource. You better google these keywords, you'll find required docs.

Comment: Elaborating my question..web app written in html5/css/javascript works fine in browser but on ipad  issues on these areas.1.On ipad default action for doubletap is zoom.How can i prevent this and override? 2.If i want to set the frame of a control separately for ipad,i need to detect the device first.How to detect the client?3.on ipad how can i detect orientation change using javascript code?